# Get a JavaScript Timer to Restart with a New Value

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm Building a JavaScript countdown timer for my first web app and need some help with it. I harvested code from around the site and stitched it together (thanks to @robbMJ) to get something that generally functions, but I need to change the value of the timer as it restarts each time.

It needs to change first from Warmup to Work Interval (workInt), then from Work to Rest and back a certain number of times (for repeated interval training). I'm having trouble changing the variable value on restart the first time, much less the second and more. Here's the code I'm using:

```
//countdownTimer code (linked externally, shown here)
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
      that = this,
      diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
}; //end CountdownTimer external code

 var warmup = 10; // The initial value
 var workInt = 5; // The work interval
 var restInt = 5; // The rest interval
 var reps = 8; // How many repetitions to do.

window.onload = function() {
  var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
  timer = new CountDownTimer(warmup); //start at warmup value
  timeObj = CountDownTimer.parse(warmup) // show warmup value


  timer.onTick(format).onTick(restart); //restart the timer
  var pause = 1000 // pause for one second as it restarts

  function restart() {
    if (this.expired()) {
     setTimeout(function() { timer.start(); }, pause);

    }
    if (this.expired()) {
     warmup = workInt; //Supposed to change warmup to WorkInt, doesn't work

/* I imagine here is where I need to put in the code to restart 
the timer the second time with the RestInt, 
third timer with WorkInt again, 
etc. until a certain number of repetitions 
but I don't know how to do that */

    }
  }
    format(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(format);

    document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function () {
    timer.start(); //start when Start is clicked
    });
    document.querySelector('#stop').addEventListener('click', function () {
    //Haven't figured out how to make the stop button work
    });
// Just formatting stuff
  function format(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
};
```

Any assistance or guidance in changing up the timer on restarts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the CountDownTimer function?

Comment: Just added it. It was linked externally, so I forgot to bring it in.